# How much RAM for angular build is fine?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-devkit

We encountered an issue while building our Angular Apps, it consumes too much memory, about 8 gigs for average project. Before blaming AngularCLI, creating a ticket and asking for help, I just want to know how much is too much for an average angular build?

The problem became sufficient when you're building it in the CI, where RAM is limited (we use a Bitbucket which has 8 gigs of ram max)

The memory consumption of `ng build` command looks as following:

1. about 3-4 gigs on the building phase
2. then it quickly rump-up up to 8gigs on the "sealing" phase

Disabling `optimisation: false` in angular.json helps to reduce max heap size to 3-4 gigs, but that left our bundles not minified and mangled, which is not acceptable.

I tried to create a heap snapshot when it consumes 7.8 gigs, but it took hours and didn't finish.

The project has about 20mb of the vendors (not optimized, so without tree-shaking and gzipping) and around 10mb of user's code.

Comment: did you manage so solve the issue / report it to Angular? We currently have the issue that on some machines builds take up to 20gb whereas they use on others only arround 1gb.

Comment: No i didn't for webpack based build. I currently migrated all projects to angular 17 and change build executor to esbuild. Thanks to hard work of angular team that works almost without changes in the codebase and effectively solve memory issue.